# Python to figure out all paths via parsing

Tags: python, parsing, data-structures, tree, logic

I have problem, that I have never dealt with before, but here it is

I have different tasks and when one task is executed, the task below is executed and so on, so the structure is like:

[image: diagram]

so now I have text file with

```
Name, Path, Time
D : A/B/C/D, -
A : A, 3 PM
B : A/B, -
Z : A/B/C/D/Z, - 
E : E, 4 PM
F : E/r/f, -
G : G, 5 PM
X : A/X, -
O : A/B/O, -
```

How do I make it print like for time

```
3 -> A
     A -> B -> C -> D -> Z
     A -> B -> O
     A -> X

4 -> E
     E -> r -> F

5 -> G
```

I want to make sure if B->C, and B->D both somehow how get displayed, like all the path that can possibly gone by this A,E,G, and ... etc.

EDIT : can you forward me to the right direction, if the question is too basic ?

Comment: I don't understand the structure of the file. (Neither the question thought…)

Comment: Hey how can I say for all top level's like A,E,G ? How can I find all the paths that follow it so, If I choose A, I should get all the paths from A.

Comment: So is this a graph question? Have you looked at networkx?

Comment: @RyanLuke sorry but I still don't get it. Top levels are marked by `PM`? Why don't you list `A -> B -> C -> D -> Z` for `A` in your example?

Comment: maybe this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting

Comment: @septi sorry for the mistake.

Comment: I updated the post, but my datset won't have that kind of issue, it would be more like the image that is displayed

Comment: This is really interesting, I'm working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
inp = """
D : A/B/C/D, -
A : A, 3 PM 
B : A/B, - 
Z : A/B/C/D/Z, 
E : E, 4 PM 
F : E/r/f, - 
G : G, 5 PM """

trans_1 = [ele.split(":")[1].strip().split(",") for ele in inp.splitlines() if ele]

trans_2 = [(ele[0].strip().replace("/", "->"), ele[1].strip()) for ele in trans_1]

#_dict = {} 

for ele in trans_2:
    if ele[1] != "-":
        #_dict[ele[1]] = []
        print ele[1], "->", ele[0]
        for inner_ele in trans_2:
            if ele[0] == inner_ele[0][0]:
                #_dict[ele[1]].append(inner_ele[0])
                print "\t", inner_ele[0]

# print _dict
```

OUTPUT:

```
3 PM -> A
        A->B->C->D
    A
    A->B
    A->B->C->D->Z
-> A->B->C->D->Z
4 PM -> E
    E
    E->r->f
5 PM -> G
    G
```

Comment: Use the commented `_dict` if you want to do more stuff or to modify

Comment: hey thanks, but it should do all the paths for A, not just A- > A/B/C/D. Thanks

Comment: Have you seen the output of this ? (updated the post)